# Jquery ui editable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating one popup using `window.open()` on click of a button.

```
$.get(url).success(function(req) {
    var win=window.open('popup.html', '', 'width=700, height=500, top=0, left(screen.width-700)');
    win.document.write(req);
```

I am having one editable field in popup and its not working. Am trying something like this,

```
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    for (var i=0; i<14; i++)
    {
        fieldname = "#sentiment_editable" + i
        $(fieldname).editable({
        inputclass: 'input-large',
        source:[
            {value:'positive', text: 'positive'},
            {value:'neutral', text: 'neutral'},
            {value:'negative', text: 'negative'}
        ]
        });
    }
    win.document.close();
});
```

The field name(tag id) is coming from ajax response(req).
In popup.html I have included below libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryui-editable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jqueryui-editable.css" />
```

Request contents is like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryui-editable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jqueryui-editable.css" />
<div id="chatterpage" class="contentArea">
<div id="allsocial" >
<div id="all_container">
<div id="eachchatter1" class="socialcontentdiv" onmouseover="document.getElementById('chatterbuttons1').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('chatterbuttons1').style.display='none'">
<table border=0 width=100%>
<tr>
<td width=60%>
<span class="socialcontent1bold">Mood: </span>
<span class="socialcontent1">
<a data-original-title="Select sentiment" data-pk="1" data-url="/Handler"  data-params='{chatterid: "5625665ba40e3cbef58de56a758d373d"}' data-type="select" data-value="neutral" id="sentiment_editable1" style="cursor:pointer" >neutral</a>
</span></td></tr>
<tr>              
<td width=60%>
<span class="socialcontent1bold">Mood: </span>
<span class="socialcontent1">
<a data-original-title="Select sentiment" data-pk="1" data-url="/Handler"  data-params='{chatterid: "fff3878b2d0e6849e9ee8408e7999892"}' data-type="select" data-value="neutral" id="sentiment_editable2" style="cursor:pointer" >neutral</a>
</span></td></tr>
</table>
</div><br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: it might help if you could include the contents of the response. ie the value that is in req from the function(req).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer was incorrect so I will try another stab at it, in the popup.html add a reference to the jquery library and add the script you are trying to execute as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jqueryui-editable.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryui-editable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    for (var i=0; i<14; i++)
    {
        fieldname = "#sentiment_editable" + i
        $(fieldname).editable({
            inputclass: 'input-large',
            source:[
               {value:'positive', text: 'positive'},
               {value:'neutral', text: 'neutral'},
               {value:'negative', text: 'negative'}
            ]
        });
     }
  });
</script>
<div id="chatterpage" class="contentArea">
<div id="allsocial" >
<div id="all_container">
<div id="eachchatter1" class="socialcontentdiv" onmouseover="document.getElementById('chatterbuttons1').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('chatterbuttons1').style.display='none'">
<table border=0 width=100%>
<tr>
<td width=60%>
<span class="socialcontent1bold">Mood: </span>
<span class="socialcontent1">
<a data-original-title="Select sentiment" data-pk="1" data-url="/Handler"  data-params='{chatterid: "5625665ba40e3cbef58de56a758d373d"}' data-type="select" data-value="neutral" id="sentiment_editable1" style="cursor:pointer" >neutral</a>
</span></td></tr>
<tr>              
<td width=60%>
<span class="socialcontent1bold">Mood: </span>
<span class="socialcontent1">
<a data-original-title="Select sentiment" data-pk="1" data-url="/Handler"  data-params='{chatterid: "fff3878b2d0e6849e9ee8408e7999892"}' data-type="select" data-value="neutral" id="sentiment_editable2" style="cursor:pointer" >neutral</a>
</span></td></tr>
</table>
</div><br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The html in the popup needs to be able to run in its own context as though it where isolated  without any knowledge that it was created with window.open. So make sure make sure popup.html works correctly first then try using window.open to open it.

Comment: Above code is not working and i have added the request contents

Comment: Just to check it looks like you are trying to do a open popup editable inside a popup.

Comment: why are you doing a win.document.close()?

Comment: I think that is the syntax

Answer (score 0):

By your code it look like that you want to have all fourteen fields to be Editable at once.If you want to convert all of the fourteen at once this is not possible because JqueryUI-Editable needs to have same class implemented over all the fourteen elements and and all of these must be binded lively as you are getting these fields from Ajax Call